# Does a Blazor WASM login work with FIDO2 and how?

Tags: blazor-webassembly, webauthn, fido

I want to create a simple Blazor WASM app, where users can login with FIDO2 (WebAuthn) instead of a password (and username perhaps) via Windows Hello, Yubikey, etc.

Google did not tell me much about FIDO2 and Blazor, I only found a library working with ASP.Net Identity, but I do not want to use Identity.

Perhaps somebody ran into that question as well? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

I am not exactly sure what you mean by not wanting to use Identity but you may find this library useful: https://github.com/abergs/fido2-net-lib

Comment: Yes thank you, already tried this library, but it's really hard without a decent documentation. But too bad there is not another solution for my problem, I guess.